# Mi problema esta en que lo que programe para que salga en "else" sale en el " if 1 y 2"

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Tu peso en otro planeta</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Tu peso en otro planeta</h1>
    <p>En la tierra pesas distinto que en <b> Marte o Júpiter</b>
    </p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // obtener valores de los usuarios:
      var usuario= prompt ("Cual es tu peso? ");
      var peso = parseInt (usuario); // Convertir en numeros...
      // "\n" Es para hacer un salto de línea
      // puedo hacer multiples funciones:
      var planeta = parseInt(prompt("Elige un planeta: \n 1: Es Marte, 2: Júpiter 3: Marte y Júpiter"))
      // asignar valores a las varibles
      var g_tierra = 9.8;
      var g_marte = 3.7;
      var g_jupiter = 24.8;

      //"if" es para poder elegir una opción
      if (planeta == 1)
      {
      var peso_final_marte = peso * g_marte / g_tierra
      // realizar los calculos y mostrarlos con document.write
      peso_final_marte = peso_final_marte.toFixed(0);
      //en paréntesis ponemos el número de decimales que queremos
      /** Las etiquetas de html en JS, van dentro de los corchetes como, si
      fuesen texto **/
      document.write ("Mi peso en <b>Marte es " + peso_final_marte + " Kg</b>"
      + "." );
      }

      if (planeta == 2)
      {
      var peso_final_jupiter = peso * g_jupiter / g_tierra
      // utilizamos este cuando querremos redondear solo con numeros enteros:
      peso_final_jupiter = parseInt (peso_final_jupiter);
      document.write ("<b> Mi peso en Júpiter es " + peso_final_jupiter
      +" Kg</b>" );
      }

      if (planeta == 3)
      {
      var peso_final_marte = peso * g_marte / g_tierra
      peso_final_marte = peso_final_marte.toFixed(0);
      var peso_final_jupiter = peso * g_jupiter / g_tierra
      peso_final_jupiter = parseInt (peso_final_jupiter);
      document.write ("Mi peso en <b>Marte es " + peso_final_marte +
      " Kg</b> y "+"<b> mi peso en Júpiter es " + peso_final_jupiter
      +" Kg</b>" );

      }

      // "else" es igual a si no...
      else
      {
      var estupides;
      estupides = "<b> Favor recargar la página y escribir una opción coherente ☺☻</b>"
      document.write (estupides + "♣");

      }
```

Comment: Tu error es que el else que pusiste al final sólo se corresponde con el último if. Btw, al trabajar con opciones es mejor usar switch-case.

Answer (score -3):

Ya pude resolverlo, tenía que usar: el siguiente código:

```
if (planeta == 1)
  {
  var peso_final_marte = peso * g_marte / g_tierra
  // realizar los calculos y mostrarlos con document.write
  peso_final_marte = peso_final_marte.toFixed(0);
  //en paréntesis ponemos el número de decimales que queremos
  /** Las etiquetas de html en JS, van dentro de los corchetes como, si
  fuesen texto **/
  document.write ("Mi peso en <b>Marte es " + peso_final_marte + " Kg</b>"
  + "." );
  }

  // Tienes que usar si no, si; para que no te salga lo que pusiste en si no en todo lo demas...
  else if (planeta == 2)
  {
  var peso_final_jupiter = peso * g_jupiter / g_tierra
  // utilizamos este cuando querremos redondear solo con numeros enteros:
  peso_final_jupiter = parseInt (peso_final_jupiter);
  document.write ("<b> Mi peso en Júpiter es " + peso_final_jupiter
  +" Kg</b>" );
  }

  else if (planeta == 3)
  {
  var peso_final_marte = peso * g_marte / g_tierra
  peso_final_marte = peso_final_marte.toFixed(0);
  var peso_final_jupiter = peso * g_jupiter / g_tierra
  peso_final_jupiter = parseInt (peso_final_jupiter);
  document.write ("Mi peso en <b>Marte es " + peso_final_marte +
  " Kg</b> y "+"<b> mi peso en Júpiter es " + peso_final_jupiter
  +" Kg</b>" );
  }

  // "else" es igual a si no...
  else
  {
  var estupides;
  estupides = "<b> Favor recargar la página y seleccionar una opción coherente ☺☻</b>"
  document.write (estupides + "♣");
  }
```

Comment: Sería mejor que explicaras el error en el código del OP fuera del código y no dentro como comentario. Además no justificas bien porque usar if-else-if funciona.